# Typing an array of elements of the same type, except the last one

Tags: typescript, tuples, typescript-typings

I have a server response which is array of IFoo elements, but the last one is IBar type.

I want to remove the last element and assign it to a new variable. How should I do that?

I've tried to type the response as a tuple, but TypeScript do not split types of the elements as I expect.

```
const response = [...IFoo[], IBar];
const lastElement = response.pop()

// typeof response returns [...IFoo[], IBar]
// typeof lastElement returns IFoo | IBar | undefined

//expected result:
// typeof response returns IFoo[]
// typeof lastElement returns IBar
```

Comment: Talking about server response, TypeScript works with static data (data already known). I don't think TypeScript can infer types dynamically from data that is available during runtime.

Can you share how you were able to determine the typeof response which returns `[...IFoo[], IBar]`? Because I'd assume that TypeScript will not know that information unless you tell it "somehow" what to expect

Comment: I don't suppose you could change the server response? It would be **much** better if it returned `[IBar, ...IFoo[]]`. Or are you stuck with what you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an unfortunate server response. Two answers for you:

1. An answer that assumes you can't change that response.
2. An answer that suggets a change to the response. :-)

### If you can't change the response

If you're stuck with that response, unfortunately you're also stuck with type assertions when unpicking the parts from it (more in [the PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41544) introducing TypeScript's handling of rest elements at the beginning or in the middle of a tuple — thanks [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) for point that out).

You have the type of the response right:

```typescript
type ResponseTuple = [...IFoo[], IBar];
```

Since we're doing type assertions, let's at least wrap them in a reusable, testable function that produces a structure that's easier to work with:

```typescript
// A function to split the response into something easier to work with
function splitResponse(response: ResponseTuple): {bar: IBar, foos: IFoo[]} {
    if (response.length < 1) {
        // No bar at all => error (you could make another decision, but this is an example)
        throw new Error(`Can't split an empty response`);
    }
    // Grab the bar non-destructively, using a type assertion :-(
    const bar = response[response.length - 1] as IBar;
    // Grab the foos non-destructively, using a type assertion :-(
    const foos = response.slice(0, -1) as IFoo[];
    // Return the more useful format
    return {bar, foos};
}
```

Using it:

```typescript
const { bar, foos } = splitResponse(someResponse);
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAUBsEMGMFMAWB7SATeAnAzqAZspqAJIBiyyo0AdmiQELSYBQAltQC5Z5zwnmUA3s1Cj8FAFyhsHTOwDmAbmYBfNp268GTUMLGgARkyky51JaubMQoACqI+HAJ4AHPsjygOD0JnjYXZGpseGZnN1AAJX9A4PhbAFcXSD4AXlAAbQA6HLIKDIBdABptTALlazBwTGQANwVQJ2QE0ERoWscfPwCgkK9XPjl5RA4JZgxYGD9QWF6OcWQARik85GUJqb5Z4PmCZAAmFYF1+EmmLbnDJmXS5W2ZUAAPKWieuMTktMy9xZK9-ZKRkwi3KVhsAEFQMleCh0FhxERsMgALbwADuDmmHEo8ng82gvhivT4eBqyPGp02+AS1FgHFYQVA8Ee0GRnwAFABKF5E95JFIVCHU2n0xnY6TJVjzbyDXl9djipGo7wNeDQbCseHitGEADWoDRUsQzDwNLpDOoEsgUtesRC7O6dvgPLeIQ+KW5uiBK0YmD+FGwR3yBRUuhEYlYngdcvgWRS5m8oAAPKBFpyw-p9DYAHKUIFUfGQSCgVIAPiZmBqRHZTRaswS6FAyOgur4NGQMqIE1YGqCgIS0sQPdAw5oTJZbI94czXkQNTRoGo6NAAFFK4R2QADADCNAA5PMAtb8Zb4GznITXfBN5zlPo1FmwABxTDQAyzvj56hBAC0GFMCTmh0kBOCUCQauYVD9BE6ohJgoqWhIP7stOMyXPm6SOsSGRYXEcbwAmiCgD+qYFFQuDEL6d5iDYL5vh+Cy4N+1B-v4siAfSwGgaA4ENAS4RttgcEIaASEofo9y7AGJaXk6WTYNaCDsgADCUP5puR-DBtRog2NEHAJJgloyk2hB8OB8CmsWBCYM2HCoX4BlGV6TD+sg2AqMoaiVKAACqEHyCOozMJJuhXH6jGgKG6RHjaMbssyrIcpyt4hb0qCxpAyDyOyQKpTYM5iAAegA-GlwQZXG2Xsns2D5WAhWiKVzBAA)

### If you can change it

**If** you can change the server response so the `IBar` is up front, things are **much** simpler:

```typescript
// The type of the response
type ResponseTuple = [IBar, ...IFoo[]];

// Dividing it up
const [ bar, ...foos] = someResponse;
console.log(bar);
//          ^? const bar: IBar
console.log(foos);
//          ^? const foos: IFoo[]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAUBsEMGMFMAWB7SATeAnAzqAZspqAJIBiyyo0AdmiQELSYBQAltQC5Z5zwnmUA3s1Cj8FAFyhsHTOwDmAbmYBfNp268GTUMLGgARkyky51JaubMQoAIKgADjAQp0WcUWzIAtvADuiFh8HJTy8BxUoJjw2A7I1Nh8eJg+zBiwMNH4AK7UsBys8aDwAB7Q3k7wABQAlFIASjFxCfAAKtmVytZgrYGgHACeDnzIeP190bHxicyDw6CNUy3tlaAAvKAA2sSMmAA0oAB0x2QUmwC65102ACKsAG6saAqgrBEdzLDTEZuGTAfHQ4EZDYc7rYplCqQao1ZRfBKoeCHSDIeRVIyYWHdfQ40AAPQA-J9pojkaiqsDsFibLixITmEA)

Comment: Shame that the server returns `[...IFoo[], IBar]` and not `[IBar, ...IFoo[]]`... otherwise we could just do `const [bar, foos] = response;`!

Comment: @vera - Indeed (but with `...`: `const [bar, ...foos] = response;`). I'd meant to commiserate with the OP on that and ask them if they could change it, but I seem to have forgot. :-)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that in [ms/TS#41544](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41544), the PR introducing leading/middle rest elements in tuple types, it explicitly says that "type assertions are required" to split such tuples into its pieces.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I've been looking for!